# Swift / CloudKit: After record changed, upload triggers "Service Record Changed"

Tags: swift, cloudkit, ckerror

**I'm trying to add a CKReference to a record in cloud kit, but the attempt keeps triggering "Service Record Changed".** From the console messages my println's have shown (console messages and code below), I'm uploading said record with 0 references, then when I attach the reference I'm seeing an attempt to upload the record with 1 reference. Then I'm getting the error.

As I understand it, **"Service Record Changed" shouldn't be triggered because the values in the Reference List have changed (the record has an entire extra field).** Even though I'm in development mode, I manually created key-value field for the Reference List, because the first record upload doesn't include the field when the reference list is empty (uploading an empty array causes another error).

I'll include code in order of relevance (you'll be able to see most of the println's) after the console messages. The whole project is on github and I can link to it or include more code if needed.

Relevant Console:

```
name was set
uploading TestCrewParticipant
with 0 references
if let projects
upload succeeded: TestCrewParticipant
attaching reference
adding TestVoyage:_d147aa657fbf2adda0c82bf30d0e29a9 from guard
references #: Optional(1)
uploading TestCrewParticipant
with 1 references
if let projects
success: 1
uploading TestCrewParticipant
with 1 references
if let projects
success: 1
local storage tested: TestCrewParticipant
u!error for TestCrewParticipant
CKError: <CKError 0x7fcbd05fa960: "Server Record Changed" (14/2004); server message = "record to insert already exists"; uuid = 96377029-341E-487C-85C3-E18ADE1119DF; container ID = "iCloud.com.lingotech.cloudVoyageDataModel">
u!error for TestCrewParticipant
CKError: <CKError 0x7fcbd05afb80: "Server Record Changed" (14/2004); server message = "record to insert already exists"; uuid = 3EEDE4EC-4BC1-4F18-9612-4E2C8A36C68F; container ID = "iCloud.com.lingotech.cloudVoyageDataModel">
passing the guard
```

Code from CrewParticipant:

```
/**
 * This array stores a conforming instance's CKReferences used as database
 * relationships. Instance is owned by each record that is referenced in the
 * array (supports multiple ownership)
 */
var references: [CKReference] { return associatedProjects ?? [CKReference]() }

// MARK: - Functions

/**
 * This method is used to store new ownership relationship in references array,
 * and to ensure that cloud data model reflects such changes. If necessary, ensures
 * that owned instance has only a single reference in its list of references.
 */
mutating func attachReference(reference: CKReference, database: CKDatabase) {
print("attaching reference")
    guard associatedProjects != nil else {
print("adding \(reference.recordID.recordName) from guard")
        associatedProjects = [reference]
        uploadToCloud(database)
        return
    }
print("associatedProjects: \(associatedProjects?.count)")
    if !associatedProjects!.contains(reference) {
print("adding \(reference.recordID.recordName) regularly")
        associatedProjects!.append(reference)
        uploadToCloud(database)
    }
}

/**
 * An identifier used to store and recover conforming instances record.
 */
var recordID: CKRecordID { return CKRecordID(recordName: identifier) }

/**
 * This computed property generates a conforming instance's CKRecord (a key-value
 * cloud database entry). Any values that conforming instance needs stored should be
 * added to the record before returning from getter, and conversely should recover
 * in the setter.
 */
var record: CKRecord {
    get {
        let record = CKRecord(recordType: CrewParticipant.REC_TYPE, recordID: recordID)

        if let id = cloudIdentity { record[CrewParticipant.TOKEN] = id }

// There are several other records that are dealt with successfully here.

print("if let projects")
        // Referable properties
        if let projects = associatedProjects {
print("success: \(projects.count)")
            record[CrewParticipant.REFERENCES] = projects
        }

        return record
    }

    set { matchFromRecord(newValue) }
}
```

generic code (which works for several other classes) where upload occurs:

```
/**
 * This method uploads any instance that conforms to recordable up to the cloud. Does not check any 
 * redundancies or for any constraints before (over)writing.
 */
func uploadRecordable<T: Recordable>
    (instanceConformingToRecordable: T, database: CKDatabase, completionHandler: (() -> ())? = nil) {
print("uploading \(instanceConformingToRecordable.recordID.recordName)")
if let referable = instanceConformingToRecordable as? Referable { print("with \(referable.references.count) references") }
    database.saveRecord(instanceConformingToRecordable.record) { record, error in
        guard error == nil else {
print("u!error for \(instanceConformingToRecordable.recordID.recordName)")
            self.tempHandler = { self.uploadRecordable(instanceConformingToRecordable,
                                                       database: database,
                                                       completionHandler: completionHandler) }
            CloudErrorHandling.handleError(error!, errorMethodSelector: #selector(self.runTempHandler))
            return
        }
print("upload succeeded: \(record!.recordID.recordName)")
        if let handler = completionHandler { handler() }
    }
}

/**
 * This method comprehensiviley handles any cloud errors that could occur while in operation.
 *
 * error: NSError, not optional to force check for nil / check for success before calling method.
 *
 * errorMethodSelector: Selector that points to the func calling method in case a retry attempt is
 * warranted. If left nil, no retries will be attempted, regardless of error type.
 */
static func handleError(error: NSError, errorMethodSelector: Selector? = nil) {

    if let code: CKErrorCode = CKErrorCode(rawValue: error.code) {
        switch code {

        // This case requires a message to USER (with USER action to resolve), and retry attempt.
        case .NotAuthenticated:
            dealWithAuthenticationError(error, errorMethodSelector: errorMethodSelector)

        // These cases require retry attempts, but without error messages or USER actions.
        case .NetworkUnavailable, .NetworkFailure, .ServiceUnavailable, .RequestRateLimited, .ZoneBusy, .ResultsTruncated:
            guard errorMethodSelector != nil else { print("Error Retry CANCELED: no selector"); return }
            retryAfterError(error, selector: errorMethodSelector!)

        // These cases require no message to USER or retry attempts.
        default:
            print("CKError: \(error)")
        }            
    }
}
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It looks like you are creating a new CKRecord every time you save.

CloudKit is returning `ServerRecordChanged` to tell you that a record with the same recordID already exists on the server, and your attempt to save was rejected because the server record's version was different.

> Each record has a change tag that allows the server to track when that record was saved. When you save a record, CloudKit compares the change tag in your local copy of the record with the one on the server. If the two tags do not match—meaning that there is a potential conflict—the server uses the value in the [*savePolicy property of CKModifyRecordsOperation*] to determine how to proceed.

Source: *[CKModifyRecordsOperation Reference](https://developer.apple.com/reference/cloudkit/ckmodifyrecordsoperation/1447488-savepolicy)*

Although you are using the `CKDatabase.saveRecord` convenience method, this still applies. The default savePolicy is `ifServerRecordUnchanged`.

First, I would suggest transitioning to **CKModifyRecordsOperation**, especially if you are saving multiple records. It gives you much more control over the process.

Second, you need to make changes to the CKRecord from the server, when saving changes to an existing record. You can accomplish this by any of the following:

1. Requesting the CKRecord from CloudKit, making changes to that CKRecord, and then saving it back to CloudKit.
2. Storing the saved CKRecord (the one returned in the completion block after saving) using the advice in the *[CKRecord Reference](https://developer.apple.com/reference/cloudkit/ckrecord#1968610)*, persisting this data, and then unarchiving it to get a CKRecord back that you can modify and save to the server. (This avoids some network round-trips to request the server CKRecord.)

> Storing Records Locally
>
> If you store records in a local database, use the encodeSystemFields(with:) method to encode and store the record’s metadata. The metadata contains the record ID and change tag which is needed later to sync records in a local database with those stored by CloudKit.

```
let record = ...

// archive CKRecord to NSData
let archivedData = NSMutableData()
let archiver = NSKeyedArchiver(forWritingWithMutableData: archivedData)
archiver.requiresSecureCoding = true
record.encodeSystemFieldsWithCoder(archiver)
archiver.finishEncoding()

// unarchive CKRecord from NSData
let unarchiver = NSKeyedUnarchiver(forReadingWithData: archivedData)  
unarchiver.requiresSecureCoding = true 
let unarchivedRecord = CKRecord(coder: unarchiver)
```

Source: *[CloudKit Tips and Tricks - WWDC 2015](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2015/715/)*

Keep in mind: you can still encounter the `ServerRecordChanged` error if another device saves a change to the record after you requested it / last saved it & stored the server record. You need to handle this error by getting the latest server record, and re-applying your changes to that CKRecord.

Comment: Thank you so much for responding. I knew there was something major that I've been missing...I need to make a lot of changes to my code!

Comment: It'll be worth it though. While you are at it, I would suggest investigating all the other possible CloudKit error codes, and think through how to handle them. A robust CloudKit app should handle every possible error appropriately (and how to do so may depend in some cases on your app).

Comment: Thanks again @breakingobstacles, did you see the method I was using for error handling? Aside from 'NotAuthenticated' I've been treating most errors as either "re-attempt with timer" or "can't retry". Are you saying I should expand my switch statement or that I should abandon a generic response altogether? I've been having a lot of trouble dealing with cloud kit's error handling so any further advice, examples, resources etc... are much appreciated.

Comment: Just got through the 2014 wwdc videos and moving on to 2015...so helpful. Thanks again for the link.

Answer (score 3):

You can use **CKModifyRecordsOperation**'s savePolicy to bypass track of change tag

`modifyRecordsOperation.savePolicy = .allKeys`