# Getting a "record to insert already exists" error for CloudKit

Tags: ios, swift, icloud, cloudkit

When I write to the public container of CloudKit, I'm getting the following error:

> CKError 0x283a01a10: "Server Record Changed" (14/2004); server message = "record to insert already exists"

I'm currently saving with the following code:

```swift
let publicCloudDatabase = CKContainer.default().publicCloudDatabase
let operation = CKModifyRecordsOperation(recordsToSave: [exampleRecord], recordIDsToDelete: nil)
let operationConfiguration = CKOperation.Configuration()

operationConfiguration.allowsCellularAccess = true
operationConfiguration.qualityOfService = .userInitiated
operation.configuration = operationConfiguration

publicCloudDatabase.add(operation)
publicCloudDatabase.save(progressRecord) { record, error in
    if let error = error {
        print("\(error)")
    } else {
        print("Success")
    }
}
```

I'm seeing in multiple posts, like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39183377/10116367) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24600308/swift-cloudkit-saverecord-error-saving-record), that I need to fetch the existing data from the server first and then modify it before uploading it again because I shouldn't be creating a new record every time.  I'm wondering if this only applies to a private container because it really doesn't make sense to fetch other people's content onto your device and modifying it before uploading it. If so, why am I getting this error and how do I resolve it.

It also doesn't make sense to me if this was a case then to only download my data within a record and modifying it before uploading it because 1)I'm not really modifying my existing data, I'm adding new data to the server and 2) the error says that the `record` already exists which means it's still going to say that the record already exists.

Comment: I don't think that's how you use `CKModifyRecordsOperation`.  If you want to create a new record, you can use the `perform` method.

Comment: @ElTomato Thank you

Comment: Records must be unique. I would look into the creation of record code and make sure that record IDs are unique.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you aren't expecting a record to be there and this is an attempt to save the record for the first time.  In that case, I think the issue is you are combining a convenience method ".save" with the method of CKModifyRecordsOperation()

So you are effectively double saving here.  Everything down to the publicCloudDatabase.add(operation) action sets up the action, and then kicks off the action, saving the record identified in the "let operation = " step.

So if you stop there, then you are good to go.

But because you then call:
publicCloudDatabase.save(progressRecord) { record, error in
///etc

That actually kicks off a separate, completely different save - hence the error!

But because you don't have a completion block on your operation, you never 'see' the results back.

Try adding this this:

```
operation.modifyRecordsCompletionBlock = { savedRecords, deletedRecordIDs, error in
    if let error = error {
         //handle error 
    } else {
        //success
    }
}
```

above this row:

```
publicCloudDatabase.add(operation)
```

That should hopefully do the trick! (don't forget to kill the .save section)

Check out the Apple documentation as well: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/cloudkit/ckmodifyrecordsoperation

Comment: You can also add a perRecordCompletionBlock if you need to take action in the event you are saving multiple records in one go.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  I'm actually adding a new entry to the server, not modifying it. In other words Entry A exists in the Record in the public container. And I want to add Entry B to the same Record.  Do I still have to fetch Entry A in order to add Entry B?

Comment: You shouldn't have to, no.  I'll edit the answer to remove the fetch/update bit - the rest should solve it *I think*